# Calculation of Correlation Matrix

Tags: correlation, independence, mixed-type-data

If we have continuoues variables $X_{1},X_{2}$ and categorical variables $C_{1},C_{2}$ (with $L+1$ levels each $C_{i}$) variables, how do we define a Correlation Matrix where we have independence across $X_{1},X_{2},C_{1},C_{2}$??

For sure we will have that $Cov(X_{i},X_{j})=1$ for $i=j$ and $Cov(X_{i},X_{j})=0$ for $i\neq j$.

However, for $Cov(X_{i},C_{i})$ and $Cov(C_{i},C_{j})$ what do we have?

Also, $C_{i}$ has $L+1$ levels, do I have to express that in a different form, with the use of one-hot encoding??

For example, let $C_{i}=(A,B,C)$ do I have to express $C_{i}$ with two different vectors, i.e. (1,0,0) and (0,1,0).

Comment: Pearson correlation coefficient is for continuous data. Well, for binary data too (called phi correlation then). It is not for categorical data with 3+ categories. That said, there exist extensions or modifications, to "correlate" two categorical variables in a manner "comparable" to Pearson r. One of them is Rk correlation. It needs that both categorical variables are of the same categories (values), and yes, its computation can be done through dummy (one-hot) variables.

Comment: Here is some info on the Rk-correlation:  https://rth.dk/resources/rk/introduction/index.html